# How to use putMany() in Flutter Objectbox?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox

I want to put a bunch of objects in Flutter Objectbox using the putMany() method instead of using a loop. I tried to generate the objects in a list and put the list, but it throws errors. My model is as simple as that:

```
@Entity()
class Careers {
  int id = 0;
  int serialNumber;
  String careerCode;
  String careerNewName;
  String careerOldName;

  Careers({
    required this.serialNumber,
    required this.careerCode,
    required this.careerNewName,
    required this.careerOldName,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that your `ObjectBox` entity class is properly annotated with `@Entity()` and that you have generated the `ObjectBox` files using the `objectbox_generator` package.

Now, create a list of `Careers` objects and use the `putMany()` method to insert them into the database

```dart
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

// code

void main() async {
  // Initialize ObjectBox store
  var store = await openStore();

  // Get the box for the Careers entity
  final box = store.box<Careers>();

  // Create a list of Careers objects
  List<Careers> careersList = [
    Careers(
      serialNumber: 1,
      careerCode: 'C1',
      careerNewName: 'Career 1',
      careerOldName: 'Old Career 1',
    ),
    Careers(
      serialNumber: 2,
      careerCode: 'C2',
      careerNewName: 'Career 2',
      careerOldName: 'Old Career 2',
    ),
  ];

  // Use putMany() to insert the list of Careers objects
  final insertedIds = box.putMany(careersList);

  print('Inserted IDs: $insertedIds');

  // Close the store when done
  await store.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, nebil. This works perfectly and super fast.